Dynamic Component Blazor Run Public Method
I have a list of references to DynamicComponents in Blazor.
Each is possibly a different type.  Each contains a method called "CodeGen"
I am trying to call the public methods, but cannot from the DynamicComponent itself.
I can use "Convert" on the "instance" to the actual type, but it still does not have a reference to the CodeGen method.
I have resorted to the following which works, but I consider sloppy.
How can I access the public method without this big if statement. I am not to sure about Generics and Interfaces which may help.
          var name = mType.Name.ToLower();
           switch (name)
           {
               case "line":
                   Line lineComponent = dynComponentObject as Line;
                   lineComponent.CodeGen(myCode);
                   break;
               case "qlabel":
                   QLabel qlabelComponent = dynComponentObject as QLabel;
                   qlabelComponent.CodeGen(myCode);
                   break;
               case "colorcomponent":
                   ColorComponent colorComponent = dynComponentObject as ColorComponent;
                   colorComponent.CodeGen(myCode);
                   break;
               case "datefield":
                   DateField df = dynComponentObject as DateField;
                   df.CodeGen(myCode);
                   break;
               case "dropdown":
                   DropDown dd = dynComponentObject as DropDown;
                   dd.CodeGen(myCode);
                   break;
               case "map":
                   Map m = dynComponentObject as Map;
                   m.CodeGen(myCode);
                   break;
               default:
                   break;
           }

I got it working using System.Reflection:
foreach (var lineItem in item.Value.componentRefs) {
    var tType = lineItem.Value.Instance.GetType();
    MethodInfo codeGenMethod = tType.GetMethod("CodeGen");
    if (codeGenMethod != null)
    {
        Object[] myObjectParms = new Object[1];
        myObjectParms[0] = myCode;
        codeGenMethod.Invoke(lineItem.Value.Instance, myObjectParms);
    }
}


I got it working using System.Reflection:  foreach (var lineItem in item.Value.componentRefs) {     var tType = lineItem.Value.Instance.GetType();     MethodInfo codeGenMethod = tType.GetMethod("CodeGen");     if (codeGenMethod != null)     {         Object[] myObjectParms = new Object[1];         myObjectParms[0] = myCode;         codeGenMethod.Invoke(lineItem.Value.Instance, myObjectParms);     } }

You should be able to define an interface that all your components implement.
public interface IMyComponent
{
    public void CodeGen();
}

And then in your code:
if (component is IMyComponent myComponent)
{
    myComponent.CodeGen();
}

